# RSpec not passing 'should save' test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

[Link to Repo](https://github.com/gjaros/ow_coaching)

I'm new to testing Rails so this is probably a very small thing but I can't figure out what's wrong. So I have some models I'd like to test. Right now the tests are simple; testing the presence of attributes and saving if all validations are met.

One of my models `Profile` `belongs_to` my `Users` model and [passes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnRx8.png) all these tests `spec/models/profiles_spec.rb`:

```html
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Profile, type: :model do
  context 'validation tests' do
    it 'ensures user_id presence' do
      profile = Profile.new(platform: 0, region: 0, tag: 'GamerTag', sr: 1600).save
      expect(profile).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'ensures platform presence' do
      profile = Profile.new(user_id: 1, region: 0, tag: 'GamerTag', sr: 1600).save
      expect(profile).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'ensures region presence' do
      profile = Profile.new(user_id: 1, platform: 0, tag: 'GamerTag', sr: 1600).save
      expect(profile).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'ensures tag presence' do
      profile = Profile.new(user_id: 1, platform: 0, region: 0, sr: 1600).save
      expect(profile).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'ensures sr presence' do
      profile = Profile.new(user_id: 1, platform: 0, region: 0, tag: 'GamerTag').save
      expect(profile).to eq(false)
    end

    it 'should save successfully' do
      profile = Profile.new(user_id: 1, platform: 0, region: 0, tag: 'GamerTag', sr: 1600).save
      expect(profile).to eq(true)
    end
  end
end
```

`app/models/profile.rb`:

```html
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  validates :platform, presence: true
  validates :region, presence: true
  validates :tag, presence: true
  validates :sr, presence:true

  belongs_to :user

  enum platform: [:pc, :xbl, :psn]
  enum region: [:us, :eu]
end
```

But then there are my other models, which "pass" all the attribute presence validation tests, which theres something wrong there because they still pass when I comment out their attribute validations and fail the `'should save successfully'` test.

The most confusing part? When I run the rails console and manually test it returns the expected value [(true)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj6Sm.png), like with my `Student` model which `belongs_to :profile`.

So I really have no idea what's going on here. Any ideas please throw them out. If you all need any more information, let me know.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I don't think I need a user to exist. When I go into my db folder and delete `development.sqlite3`,  `test.sqlite3` and `schema.rb`, run `rails db:migrate` and then `rspec`, the `profile_spec.rb` still passes all tests.
This is Rails 5.2

Comment: Ah, looks like I completely misunderstood the question...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So why does `profile_spec.rb`'s `should save successfully` test pass and the other model's versions of the test don't? They all have the same basic tests as `profile_spec.rb`, they all have foreign keys in the schema and `belongs_to` associations in their models. There is SOMETHING different about `Profile` but I don't understand what it is. Unless I'm misunderstanding you I still don't see what's causing this.

Comment: If you cook up a [mcve] with both "good" and "bad" files, I'll take a look.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I added a link to the repo at the top of the post. The state of my project's models and tests right now are still very simple so I don't know how I could make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: That should be enough. Let me see.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you for your time. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it's an error of missing related records. Let's take coach spec, for example:

```
it 'should save successfully' do
  coach = Coach.new(profile_id: 1, roles: ['tank']).save
  expect(coach).to eq(true)
end
```

Here (in my experiments) there's no profile with id=1. In fact, there are no profiles at all. So this spec fails, as expected.

Buuuut, by the time we get to the profile spec:

```
it 'should save successfully' do
  profile = Profile.new(user_id: 1, platform: 0, region: 0, tag: 'GamerTag', sr: 1600)
  expect(profile).to eq(true)
end
```

user with id=1 **does** exist (likely because user spec was run before this one and successfully created a user record).

Lessons to learn:

1. **Always** clean/rollback database between tests (or otherwise make it pristine)
2. **Always** run tests in a randomized order. Spec order dependency can be very difficult to detect, as you can see in this thread.

Comment: @Sergio_Tulentsev I haven't checked to see if this is right but I have a feeling it is. There were a couple times where after I deleted my `test.sqlite3` db, the `profile_spec.rb` tests didn't pass but upon the second run they did. I don't know why I didn't put two-and-two together but I'll configure rspec to test randomly and to rollback as well as seed some stuff to make sure that I get the right outcome. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are writing tests in a really inefficient way. If you wan't to test validations, then you don't need to test the `save` method return value but the value of the `valid?` method AND the `errors` hash.

```
RSpec.describe Profile, type: :model do
  context 'validation tests' do
    it 'ensures user_id presence' do
      profile = Profile.new(platform: 0, region: 0, tag: 'GamerTag', sr: 1600, user_id: nil) #you should be explicit with the user_id value being nil, tests should be explicit, it may seem unnecesary but it makes them easier to read
      expect(profile).to be_invalid #or expect(profile).not_to be_valid
      expect(profile.errors[:user_id]).to be_present #you could test the actual message too, not just the presence on any error
    end
  end
end
```

That test actually tests only validations and also ensures that there's an error on the `user_id` field.

With your actual test you cannot know what is actually preventing the object to be saved. It could be anything: another validation, a before_save callback returning false, an invalid value when inserting into the database, anything. It's also slower since it has to actually write the record on the database, testing `valid?` is done on memory which is a lot faster.

Id' recommend you to read about FactoryBot so you don't have to repeat `Profile.new....` on each test.

If you still want to test the return value of `save` on the last test, you have to know WHY it's not being saved, you con use `save!` which raises an exception instead of returning false to debug your code, and you can also inspect `profile.errors.full_messages` to see if there are any errors that you didn't consider when setting up the test.

Comment: Yes, those expectations are not the best :)

Comment: I was following a tutorial on youtube...guess that wasn't a good idea. I'll definitely look into factory bot to dry up my tests too. Thank you for the feed back!

Comment: @GregoryJaros: that tutorial likely didn't use any fixtures or factories on purpose, to not distract viewers from whatever the main point was (presumably, testing). But in real world we do use those things to help us write better specs.